# Fonts problem in Google Chrome for Mac

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

Sometimes I open up websites in Google chrome and the fonts look busted like this:
[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/324237/chrome-fonts.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/324237/chrome-fonts.png)

I've see a variety of fixes for this posted around forums, but none that reliably worked.  Has anyone solved this for good?

Answer (score 0):

I suffered this same issue and nothing worked to resolve it. I recently used Chromatic to update to the very latest build, and the problem resolved itself.

Comment: Cool - if it's in Chromatic (which I guess is the developer branch), then that means it should be coming to the main Chrome soon right?